# Is there some simple developer tools / IDE for mac ?

Tags: macos

I need to write simple application that will run on mac. 
The application need to take some text file and send it over http ( using REST ).

Is there some free IDE that i can download and use ? 
If i will write it in java - is it run on mac ?

Thanks.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/172496)

Comment: Why is this tagged as iOS? Do you want an application in Java, C, C++ or Objective-C? It really isn't very clear.

Comment: iOS *does not run on a mac*. Either you mean OSX, or you don't mean you want to run it on a mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the question applies here, but if you want to write Java use Eclipse. It is free and runs on Mac.